# Why do big sites use 'bad practices'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I often see articles, posts and comments something like:

- globals are bad in javascript
- script tags should be at bottom of page
- CSS should be in external files and at the top of page
- scripts should be in external files, not plain script-tags.
- etc.

I've looked up the HTML source of some big sites and have noticed that they have a lot of plain javascript and CSS inside HTML markup. JavaScript and HTML are note always obfuscated, and so on.

Comment: Try hiring a large team of developers, then try getting them to hit deadlines and follow best practises all the time. It isn't easy.

Comment: Isn't MySpace one of the best examples of a large site build very poorly? If I recall correctly, wasn't it originally built in tables? Maybe it's changed since then?

Comment: sometimes "fast release" could be the best way

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are quite a few separate issues here.

1. What you see when you "view source" is not usually what they develop with. It's usually a compressed / optimised form generated from "source" code.
2. Claims about what is "best practice" are necessarily generic, and don't apply to all scenarios (especially if you're a big site and need specialised optimisation). These guidelines should be considered individually for each project.
3. Best practice, or even clean code, doesn't directly translate to return on investment. It may be nice to have consistent naming schemes, but is it worth the time developing and enforcing the scheme across 100s of developers?
4. Laziness, incompetence, or Friday nights.

Answer (score 6):

Just because a site is big makes no guarantees about the quality of the code.

Have you ever viewed the source of Google's page? Is it pretty? No. Does it work? Yes!

Comment: but may be it can work better :)) When I have been opening source-pages of big sites, I've expected few css-links at the top (to minify number of requests), obfuscated html, and then few javascript-src tags..

Comment: mm, so if you big enough the "rules" don't apply. Maybe that is how you became big in the first place...

Comment: HTML is almost never obfuscated since it's completely useless (Firebug, "View generated source", etc.). Removing some whitespace is often done for compression though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - yes, I know that HTML-obfuscation is only for compressing matters

Comment: Google - "Does it work? Yes!" If you ignore the JavaScript errors under IE7 (which I'm forced to use at work). Only a problem if JavaScript debugging options are on and you type in the search box - in other words, everytime I try to use it.

Comment: @nnnnnn Google dropped legacy browser support. Convince your work to use a competent browser.

Comment: @Raynos - beyond my control I'm afraid (big government department). Though IE7 still kind of feels like a step *up* because this time last year I was stuck with IE6 (at a different government department).

Comment: @nnnnnn Dont work for government :) unless you want to be shackled by bureacry and IT departments

Answer (score 6):

Some possible reasons:

1. Some Web code simply isn't very big or complicated and it really makes no difference in maintainability whether it follows best practices or not, and it works fine the way it is.
2. Code is often written by inexperienced programmers, even on big, popular sites, and is never improved because it works fine the way it is.
3. Best practices change from time to time and it's seen as wasteful to spend time redoing your code just to adhere to the latest, when it works fine the way it is.
4. Adding new features is deemed more important than cleaning up old code, especially when, again, the old code works fine the way it is.

You may sense a recurring theme here. Rarely do programmers feel the need to fix what isn't broken.

Edit: If I were writing this now, more than two years later, I'd reword that final sentence to say "Rarely does *management* feel the need to fix what isn't broken." Most programmers love to revamp inelegant things, to the extent that they must sometimes be restrained by management in order to ship a product. I'd also throw in a mention of the concept of [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: +1 *Rarely do programmers feel the need to fix what isn't broken*

Comment: Another thing I should note is, Web development is no different from any other development in this regard. You would be surprised at how messy the source code for some of your favorite applications is, particularly those which were developed in a hurry. The only difference is, most of the time you never see the source code for those apps, while on the Web it is readily accessible.