# Why do most websites have their HTML in just a few lines?

Tags: html

I searched for this question-- both in Google and Stackoverflow-- but couldn't find what I wanted.

Now, whenever I see the source code of a website, like Facebook or Google, their HTML code is spanned in just one line? Why do they do it? What is the significance of doing it? Do I need to do it for small websites as well, say maybe a school website?

Comment: they minify their code to reduce bandwidth usage

Comment: So, it makes the web page load faster?

Comment: What you're looking at is "minified" HTML, javascript, and CSS. Basically, they still write the code and markup normally, but run it through a process to strip out unnecessary whitespace, shorten variable names, and whatever they can to shrink the size of it, so it's as few bytes as possible. When you're dealing with billions of requests, saving a few bytes of bandwidth with each request really adds up. For a regular business site, it probably makes very little difference.

Comment: One related thing to consider - for most sites, minifying may not make a huge difference, but compression really does. So make sure you've got GZip compression turned on, at least for your static files (HTML, CSS, JS). That usually makes a huge reduction in bandwidth and improvement in performance.

Comment: OK, so, say that I've compressed the files and removed most of the whitespaces from the source code as possible; won't the latter part make the code difficult to maintain? Or do I need to create a separate file just for the sake of maintenance and have to update the new code in both the files-- properly indented and most of the whitespaces removed?

Comment: you make code with comments, tab, spaces etc... when it's the time to push it online, then you run a tool that compress, concats and minify all your code (with settings that you decide)

Comment: see Gruntjs (http://gruntjs.com/) for example. But there are serveral tools like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main Google page server millions of page views every hour. If it's one byte longer, that means gigabytes of additional data are transferred over the Internet every day.

That's why big sites with lots of traffic really squeeze every bit out of their HTML code. For small sites, this isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here'a a StackOverflow answer with a lot of reasons why web sites use "bad practices" in general: [Why do big sites use 'bad practices'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261342/why-do-big-sites-use-bad-practices)

As others have said, though, the "one big line" issue is usually motivated by both performance considerations and obfuscation.

Frankly, unless you're serving hundreds (thousands?) of page load per minute, I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Aaron Digulla, its used to keep byte size down.

Its also used to remove whitespaces (which can cause errors in php&js), comments and also to keep pesky people from trying to steal code. In minified form, its harder to read and therefore harder to copy.

Answer (score 1):

We called that "minification" (remove unnecessary information from the code (White spaces, comments etc.) ). not only for html, you can do that it for javascript, css etc as well. Minification improves overall performance of the application.

Wikipedia explanation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29

You can apply that for small web sites as well. There are tools available for that and it is a best practice as well.